Having problem understanding "a- occurs in words which have "not", "without", or "opposite to" as part of their meaning."
I just started to read the book "Word Formation" by "John Sinclair". The book explains the meaning of some prefixes and suffixes. It starts with:

a-
a- occurs in words which have "not", "without", or "opposite to" as part of their meaning. For example, someone who is "apolitical" has no opinions about political matters and takes no interest in them.

I found the first sentence very confusing. I understand that the author intends to say that when the prefix a- appears in words, it can make the words to have "not", "without" or "opposite to" as part of their meaning.
But the way it is stated doesn't make sense to me, as I would interpret it as the words themselves, without the prefix a-, have "not", "without" or "opposite to" as part of their meaning. I'm wondering if I am missing something, or this part of the book is ambiguous.
Edit:
After reading the sentence several times, I guess the word "which" can refer to the prefix a- but in this case it should be "which has" maybe there is a typo?

You've done well to work it out. You can reinforce your understanding by imagining what it might have said: a- is added to words which have "not" ... as part of their meaning. That would definitely mean what you first thought.

The prefix itself conveys the notion of "not".   "apolitical" is "not political". "atheist" is not believing in a Deity.   "asocial" means "not social, not given to socializing".

The explanation is very clear: a- occurs in words which have "not", "without", or "opposite to" as part of their meaning. So: in asocial there is a + social. In apolitical there is a + political. How are those not clear? "as* is  one part of the meaning, social is another: asocial. atypical: a + typical=without the characteristic of typical. For example. amorphous: a + without shape: morphous.

Well, okay, maybe the sentence is poorly worded. The intended meaning is that attaching the prefix "a-" negates or reverses the meaning of the word. Like, "typical" means "common", "atypical" means not typical or not common. Etc.

Thanks for the answer. It is very strange as the author repeated this pattern for some other prefixes (I haven't read the book thoroughly but could find two other examples): "electro- occurs in words which have 'electric' as part of their meaning."
"equi- occurs in words which have 'equal', or 'equally' as part of their meaning."

@Soheil Well not that strange! If the other came up with some words to express an idea, even if they were not a very good or clear way to say it, it's not surprising that he would re-use those words for the same idea elsewhere!

Part of the sentence :

a- occurs in words which have "not", "without", or "opposite to" as part of their meaning.

Breaking the sentence into parts
[a- occurs in words] [which have "not", "without", or "opposite to" as part of their meaning.].
I. a- occurs in words..

Ref. Collins dictionary
occur.
: to be found or met with : appear

So the words in which a- is the prefix are
apathetic,
asocial,
atheist,
amorphous,
Ii. which have "not", "without", or "opposite to" as part of their meaning..
which= these words or words with a- as prefix.
All the words have 'not' as part of their meaning.
apathetic: ‘not’ caring.
asocial: ‘not’ social.
atheist: ‘not’ believing in a deity.
amorphous: ‘not’ having a shape
